# Chrome showing "canceled" on successful file download (200 status)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, download

Not sure if this is an actual problem or not, but I'm writing a file out in ASP.NET, and even though the file always successfully goes through, in Chrome's developer tools, network tab, I always see the line in red, marked "Canceled".

I've tried lots of ways of doing this - for simplicity, I'm trying this with a simple text file, but it's true for PDF and other file types as well.

WebForms: I've tried it with lots of combinations of the following:

```
Response.Clear();
// and/or/neither
Response.ClearHeaders();

// with and without this
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.Charset = "";
// or/neither
Response.Charset = "utf-8";

// application/pdf for PDF, also tried application/octet-stream
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

// with and without this
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=1.txt");

// bytes is the UTF8 bytes for a string or the PDF contents
new MemoryStream(bytes).WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
// or
Response.Write("12345");

// any combination of the following 3, or none at all
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

MVC (2 and 3, haven't tried 4):

```
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345");
return File(fileContents, "text/plain", "1.txt");
// or
return File(@"C:\temp\1.txt", "text/plain", "1.txt");
```

It's always the same - the file goes through just fine, but dev tools shows me this:
[image: dev tools network output]

I'm thinking of just ignoring it and moving on with life, but the red just bothers me. Any idea how I can deal with that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This just means that chrome didn't navigate away from the page.  The behavior is by design.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought maybe that was the case, but I couldn't find any documentation or discussions anywhere that stated this was normal. It would be nice if it was a little clearer that it's not an error - but I guess I can suggest that to the dev team.