# Struts 2 stream type causes request to fail

Tags: java, http, servlets, struts2

I have a result of type stream that when is returned from an action call, causes this error to be output into the console.

```
<action name="process" class="com.moog.app.docparser.actions.ProcessAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload" />
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
            <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${newFileName}"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
        </result>
        <result name="error" type="redirect">
            index.action?notSupported=${notSupported}
        </result>
  </action>
```

[image]

The file does download, but causes the request to fail.  Is there a reason that a result of type stream causes the request to fail?  I understand that it is recieving the data from the file rather than another page to load, but isn't the file a valid response?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15393210/1700321.